# One of my users who has valid fcm token, can't receive notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I am storing users FCM tokens in the database each time they got in. When I heard one of my users says he can't get notification, to test him phone I sent notification via his token. But he can't get it also he can't get subscribe any topic.

Token is valid, syntax is correct, notification settings are okay. I am using Firebase 10.2 on iOS, should I use any other services like OneSignal or Braze? What could be the problem and how to solve?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.